# Error javascript function to get value out of static php drop down

Tags: php, javascript, combobox

I made the dropdown with PHP which works fine. When the selected item changes, I call the function changePeriod().

```
$options[0] = '--period--';
$options[1] = 'Daily';
$options[2] = 'Weekly';
$options[3] = 'Monthly';

<td><?php echo form_dropdown('period', $options, '0', 'id="period" onchange="changePeriod()"'); ?></td>
```

Here you can see the HTML source code which is a result of the code above.

```
<td>
   <select name="period" id="period" onchange="changePeriod()">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">--period--</option>
      <option value="1">Daily</option>
      <option value="2">Weekly</option>
      <option value="3">Monthly</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

In this function I need to get the value of the selected item, but the 2 alerts above the switch both give **Undefined** as a result. Does anyone has an idea why I get undefined and not the values of the selected option? It worked with a dynamic dropdown filled with a foreach from the database.

```
function changePeriod() {
    alert(document.getElementById("period").selectedIndex);
    alert(document.getElementById("period").value);

    switch (document.getElementById("period").selectedIndex) {
        case 1:
            alert("daily");
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("weekly");
            break;
        case 3:
            alert("monthly");
            break;
    }
}
```

**Basically:** Why can't I get the values of the selected option and how can I fix it?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why you are not using jQuery?

Comment: What's the HTML generated by `form_dropdown()`?

Comment: can you show us what the form_dropdown function looks like, and would be good to examine the form via DeveloperTools or similar (depending on your browser) to make sure the period id is being correctly injected into the DOM

Comment: Yes, JS seems correct, show us the HTML.

Comment: @OğuzhanEroğlu - What kind of question is that?

Comment: What more of the HTML do you need to see? The first code is how I filled the dropdown with php/html.

Comment: @user2066100 - [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/8QF3u/).

Comment: We need to see the `<select>...</select>` part, to check if it actually includes `id="period"`.

Comment: @user2066100 See http://jsfiddle.net/8QF3u/ that Joseph Silber created. That should help you find your problem, from what you've posted, it should work

Comment: Are you creating multiple of these elements on one page?

Comment: @JuanMendes I also got a dropdown on that page but it's dynamically filled with a foreach loop without any problems

Comment: @JuanMendes I also tried that, but it doens't work either.

Comment: @bfavaretto I added the generated HTML code but that looks fine. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No... Did you check the browser's console for js errors?

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTML generated like this:

```
<select onchange="changePeriod()" id="period">
        <option value="0">--period--</option>
        <option value="1">Daily</option>
        <option value="2">Weekly</option>
        <option value="3">Monthly</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changePeriod(event) {
            alert(document.getElementById("period").selectedIndex);
            alert(document.getElementById("period").value);

            switch (document.getElementById("period").selectedIndex) {
                case 1:
                    alert("daily");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    alert("weekly");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    alert("monthly");
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

If yes, it works for me.

Why don't you use jquery, you could do everything with less code.

EDIT:

The solution with jQuery:

```
$("#period").change(function(){
   alert("The Value: "+$(this).val());
   switch ($(this).val()) {
            case 1:
                alert("daily");
                break;
            case 2:
                alert("weekly");
                break;
            case 3:
                alert("monthly");
                break;
        }
});
```

take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/rfWjd/

Comment: I first tried with something like this. 
function changePeriod() { alert($( 'period' ).val()) } but it had the same result.

Comment: @user2066100 Should be `alert($('#period' ).val())` so that you're looking by ID, but there's no need for jQuery

Comment: @JuanMendes jQuery is never needed cause it's nothing more than javascript, but it's useful and can save a lot of time.